# Transforming a tree back to JSON using tree-model-js

Tags: javascript, json, tree, treemodel

Is there perhaps a way in which you can convert a TreeModel to a JSON string. That way it can be stored and then later recreated using `tree.parse()`?

Currently when attempting `JSON.stringify(root)` it gives an obvious error about cyclic references (because children contain parents and parents contain children).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `JSON.stringify(root.model)` instead.